# :hover not working properly

Tags: html, css

Please view the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/9AbvE/291/

What happens is that when I hover over element `div id = f12` the `div id = floater` will change background color, but when I hover over `div id = f11`, it doesnt change color, anyone has any idea why ?

Much thanks!

Strictly CSS solutions only, thanks!

Here is there css for viewing

```
#f11
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
}
#f11:hover + #floater
{
    background:blue;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    opacity:100;
    right:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#f12
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
}

#f12:hover + #floater
{
    background:blue;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    opacity:100;
    right:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#floater
{
    width: 320px;
    height:320px;
    opacity:0;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: 1s all;
    -moz-transition: 1s all;
    transition: 1s all;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe lets start from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change 
`#f11:hover + #floater`

to

`#f11:hover ~ #floater`

`+` is for immediate sibling after element whereas `~` is for any sibling after element

Answer (score 1):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/9AbvE/312/)

You were missing `;` from your `background:black` because of that it was not showing any color and your `div`'s are not far away which is leading to corrupt function. Give `top:50px;` (or more) to `#f12`.
and also use the `sibling` selector as @ClydeLobo said.